# Having MSDN on a usb key

Tags: msdn, portability, portable-applications

Is there a way to have msdn documentation on a usb key ?
either web or the MSDN Library program.
i've been setting up my usbkey with portableapps stuff.

Answer (score 1):

i think when you do step 2 and install the documentation just tell direct it to the usb key drive letter. easy peasy.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work or not. While that would install the actual MSDN docs to the usb key, you'd still need to make sure that the Documentation Explorer software was installed by the system. I don't think that can be customized during the installation, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Visual Studio 2012/2013 Help Downloader](http://vshd2012.codeplex.com/). This tool allows Visual Studio 2012/2013 packages to be downloaded to an offline cache location before being imported into the Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0/2.1 for offline viewing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@Oleg You can use [MSDN to USB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Moataz99.MSDNtoUSB), it works offline with any Visual Studio 2010|2015|2017|2019 IDE product.

Apparently, you've to download the docs 1st, then use this tool to "**Backup MSDN**" to your USB drive, later use the same tool to "**Locate MSDN**".